# jQuery portfolio toggle messing with position

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

i've a portfolio grid with images, with a jQuery toggle on each image.

When i click an image its look like this:
[image]

And i want to be like this:
[image]

I don't want that my toggle info, push down my portfolio images, maybe I know why its happening, but still can't solve it.

HTML:

```
    <div id="blog">
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
    <div class="post" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'mainimg' ); ?>               
        </div>
        <div class="toggleSection">
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <h3>Posted in: <span><?php the_category(', ') ?>  </span>On: <span><?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?></span></h3>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?> </p>
        </div>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #blog {
position: relative;
height: 900px;
width: 905px;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: 10px;
clear: both;
    }

    .thumbnail {
z-index: 0;
float: left;
margin: 4px 3px 0px 3px;
cursor: pointer;
    }

    .toggleSection {
margin: 0 auto;
clear: both;
display: none;
background-color: pink;
height: 300px;
width: 900px;
    }
```

New into many things, please help :)

Comment: I don't really understand the difference between your two screenshots. On what image did you click ?

Comment: I would like, that when I click any image, looks like second screenshot. In the first screenshot i clicked the third image, and it split my column (because of the natural flow)

Comment: I want that columns are always with 5 items per row. No matter what image I click

Comment: You're going to have to change your page structure. You need to organize your images in different divs, one for each line. Then, when you click on an image, you just append the toggle section after your "line-div"

Comment: But i'm using the thumbnails of the post loop on wordpress, can't separate image per div.

Comment: Take a look at [Google Image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=world&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=GRaIUdCKFcnEyQH1-oCwDw&biw=1920&bih=947&sei=HRaIUa3rKJTCyAGnz4G4Cw#imgrc=I6mUIX2BemSxbM%3A%3ByS-RLjkZmDf4LM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fscienceblogs.com%252Fstartswithabang%252Ffiles%252F2012%252F12%252Fglobe_west_2048.jpeg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fscienceblogs.com%252Fstartswithabang%252F2012%252F12%252F20%252Fthe-science-of-the-real-end-of-the-world%252F%3B2048%3B2048) - they do this.

Comment: Yes, like Google image search, but not at full width.

Comment: Hold on, I'm going to give you a working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following :

Get the index of the image clicked with [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

```
var currentIndex = $('.image').index(this);
```

Then find the closest image that is a multiple of 5, and above the current index with [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
  var nextFiveMultiple = (Math.floor((currentIndex+5) / 5) * 5)-1;
```

Once you found it, you append the `toggleSection`container.

```
$('.image:eq('+nextFiveMultiple+')').after('<div class="toggle"></div>');
```

**Here is a general jsfiddle if people are stumbling upon that thread:**

http://jsfiddle.net/rNUDm/2/

Here is another edit of that jsfiddle, that will fit your specific code :

http://jsfiddle.net/rNUDm/3/